# Compatibility issue for tables on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table, compatibility

I have a responsive theme and everything works great on phones and pc's. The only problems is the tables get cut off. This has not been a problem before but I have now included WPMUDEV Membership and the registration table gets cut off, so the paypal button is not accessible. This is a nuisance as it means customers have to sign up on a PC so I could miss out on sales.

An example can be seen here: http://www.thetippingteam.com/register/?action=registeruser&subscription=6

Any assistance would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

check the width of your tables.
if they are set to "px" it might give problems.
you should keep it as "%"